# How to create private route in nextjs using supabase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, supabase

I am using supabase as backend and I want to create private route for all my pages. I use getServerSideProps to fetch some data and When I read some related documentation about private route(nextjs) there is one problem next doesnot allowed us to use both getInitialProps and getServerSideProps in same page. So How to solve this problem.

I am trying to create private route in nextjs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication